# pre, in, and post order of an arithmetic tree [scheme/racket]

Tags: tree, scheme, racket, tree-traversal

Imagine an arithmetic expression such as (+ 1 (* 2 (- 3 5))) being thought of as a tree-like structure with numbers at the leaves and operator symbols at the interior nodes like below:

```
     +
   /   \
  1     *
       /  \
      2    -
          /  \
         3    5
```

I have these functions already defined to access certain parts of the tree:

```
;; returns tree node
(define (operator lst)
  (cadr lst))

;; returns left tree
(define (left-op lst)
  (car lst))

;; returns right tree
(define (right-op lst)
  (cddr lst))
```

I am trying to write 3 functions `preorder`, `inorder`, and `postorder` that return a list of the tree traversed in the order they were encountered

I know how the tree traversal works from previous java programming but am having trouble coding this

ex for above:
`(preorder '(+ 1 (* 2 (- 3 5))))` => `(+ 1 * 2 - 3 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of trees is not quite right, you need to represent a leaf (a number in the examples) as another tree with null left and right subtrees. Also, it's useful having a `make-tree` "constructor". Let's go step-by-step - first, a correct abstraction for representing trees:

```
(define (make-tree value left right)
  (list left value right))

(define (operator tree)
  (cadr tree))

(define (left-op tree)
  (car tree))

(define (right-op tree)
  (caddr tree))
```

Now for the traversals. I'll help you with the first one, `preorder`:

```
(define (preorder tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      '()
      (append (list (operator tree))
              (preorder (left-op tree))
              (preorder (right-op tree)))))
```

The tree in the question would look like this:

```
(define tree
  (make-tree '+
             (make-tree 1 '() '())
             (make-tree '*
                        (make-tree 2 '() '())
                        (make-tree '-
                                   (make-tree 3 '() '())
                                   (make-tree 5 '() '())))))
```

Use it like this:

```
(preorder tree)
> '(+ 1 * 2 - 3 5)
```

The other two traversals are very similar, just rearrange the three arguments for `append` in the correct order for each case - I'll let that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer - thanks to data abstraction, you only need to change the accessor procedures, the algorithm remains unchanged.

Comment: The above code works, copy-paste all of it and try again - you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Are you using `#lang racket` ? It's the only think I can think of, sorry, but it works for me.

Comment: Didn't you _read_ the answer? the sample tree in my code is exactly that tree! you can't pass `(+ 1 (* 2 (- 3 5)))` to the `preorder` procedure and expect it to work, you _have to_ use `make-tree` to create the tree, as explained above!

Comment: Transform the input to my suggested representation, it's easy. The algorithm won't work for trees that are not correctly formed, you need to represent them as I suggest.